# Using PHP, Thrift and Django

Tags: django, thrift

I am planning for a application which enables to use PHP as Frontend and Django as backend for API Platform. My question is it possible to use Django with Thrift as we use in regular MVC (without HTTP requests instead Onject in Thrift).

Or is there any other alternative to use PHP and Django?

Answer (score 2):

Just use Django.  Why would you try to mix the two?  You haven't explained why there are two systems here in the first place.

Comment: this is requirement of my system which has existing frontend on PHP (Can't be shifted), and I want to use Django's features for API Platform.

Comment: but why not use PHP for the API platform also? Much as I dislike PHP I would be very reluctant to re-implement all that logic. I understand that using Thrift abstracts some of the data but... so what?